# Cancel Subscriptions and Asynchronous tasks in a useEffect during AXIOS POST

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, axios

I'm receiving the following error when I execute the below code.

I want to basically sets some property which are used in the "render" of this "RFC" file so it can update when it reaches in the necessary point.

Error:

**Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.**

Code:

```
function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState('');
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);

  async function onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    setIsLoading(true);

    await api.post(urls.LOGIN, {
      email,
      password
    }).then(handleSuccess.bind(this))
      .catch(handleError.bind(this))
      .finally(handleAlways.bind(this));
  }

  function handleSuccess(response) {
    setError(false);
    setErrorMsg('');
    setIsLoggedIn(true);
    setToken(response.data.token);
  }

  function handleError(e) {
    setError(true);
    setErrorMsg(e.response.data.message);
    setIsLoggedIn(false);
    setToken('');
  }

  function handleAlways() {
    setIsLoading(false);
  }

  function onChangeEmail(value) {
    setError(false);
    setErrorMsg('');
    setEmail(value);
  }

  return (
    <div className="page">
      {isLoggedIn ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <form></form> }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Usage:

```
{isLoggedIn ? <Redirect to="/" /> : <form blablabla...</form>}
```

Comment: where is the rest of the component?

Comment: @adamz4008 just added.

Comment: is Login component becoming unmounted during any point? What line does the stack trace w/that error point to?

Comment: @adamz4008 it is not unmounted. I couldn't understand why its necessary. And i couldn't apply to a POST request.

Comment: @adamz4008 the error is on the "setToken(response.data.token);"

Comment: Oh, right before it is `isLoggedIn` change, then redirected. So that is why it is unmounted. So try updating your state in objects instead of multiple `useState`s. Like  email and password can be part of ` formState` and the rest in `loginState` or something. That way it's updated all at once and you don't have to worry about that individual update triggering the redirect

Comment: That's the easy version but long term you'll probably want to look into storing loginState in a global data component using React Context https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: @adamz4008 Hi man, I've tried what you mentioned, but still, with the same error. Check the link for the code: http://dontpad.com/59187848

Comment: @adamz4008 the error is now on the `_handleAlways` fn

Comment: @adamz4008 I've could fix it by doing this: https://prnt.sc/q6frtb

Comment: Got it. I just explained my comment in an answer to make it more clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Previous:

  // Form state
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

  // Auth state
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState(false);
  const [errorMsg, setErrorMsg] = useState('');
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState('');
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false);
*/

/* New
  This uses objects so order of updates doesn't matter.

  For example, in previous implementation setting logged
  and then setting loading causes an error, because updating logged
  causes a redirect and component is unmounted.

  By grouping state into domains using an object, rather than individual
  useState()'s, you can update it all at once
  and not have to worry about which order you can update state variables in.
*/

const [formState, setFormState] = useState({ email: '', password: '' })

const [authState, setAuthState] = useState({
  token: '',
  error: '',
  errorMsg: '',
  isLoading: false,
  isLoggedIn false
})

// Example usage

setAuthState({
  ...authState,
  error: 'Some error msg'
})
```